# Play a YouTube video on iPhones, in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, ios, youtube

I have a simple site with no mobile version.

I know how to target iPads and iPhones via user-agent (via http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/), but what I want is that when a user enters, instead of seeing the website, he should see a video from YouTube. Preferably in fullscreen and with autoplay.

What is the "normal" way of doing this ?

Comment: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application

Comment: @user2545330 so basically I would just have to redirect to YouTube, and the iPhone takes care of the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to go to the video that you want to add get the embedded code for the size that you like,
like this one:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WOoUVeyaY_8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and then add in the end of the "src" this:

```
?autoplay=1
```

it shoud look like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WOoUVeyaY_8?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```